# React JS nested conditions, unexpected error on .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to do nested conditionals to be rendered and one case would make me use `.map()`

```
renderClasses () {
        if (!this.state.classes.length) {
            console.log(this.state.userType)
            if (this.state.userType) return(<div>Add Class</div>)
            else return (<div>Join Class</div>)
        } else {
            return (<div>{
                this.state.classes.map((class) => {
                                             ^ unexpected token here 
                    <div>one class</div>
                })
            }</div>)
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isLogged) {
            return <Redirect to='/' />
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.renderClasses()
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Am i missing something? i tried wrapping everything into one `<div>` or maybe I understood it wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50329714/react-loop-within-a-loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you do not return anything:

```
this.state.classes.map((item) => {
   <div>one class</div>
})
```

try to paste `return` statement

```
this.state.classes.map((item) => {
   return <div>one class</div>
})
```

But the error is cause by `class` being a **reserved keyword**, try to name it like `item`.

Comment: This is right. It's worth noting that `return` is only required with the curley braces. So for example, both of these would return a div. `.map(class => <div>One class</div>)` and `.map(class => { return <div>One class</div> })`

Comment: i forgot about this, thank you for reminding about reserved keywords!

Comment: @adv I'm glad it works. If I helped please upvote or accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `{}` in `map` function you need to use `return` as well. If its just a single statement, just ignore `{}`. You can use this -

```
this.state.classes.map(class => <div>one class</div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try returning from the map like this:

```
renderClasses () {
        if (!this.state.classes.length) {
            console.log(this.state.userType)
            if (this.state.userType) return(<div>Add Class</div>)
            else return (<div>Join Class</div>)
        } else {
            return (<div>{
                this.state.classes.map((class, index) => {
                    return (<div key={index}>one {class}</div>)
                })
            }</div>)
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isLogged) {
            return <Redirect to='/' />
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.renderClasses()
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
```